# Preserving a bijection between arrays when shuffling elements in one array

Tags: list-manipulation

Imagine I have two lists of elements like the following:

```
listOne = RandomReal[{0,2}, {100,2}];
listTwo = RandomReal[{0,2}, {100,2}];
```

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a bijection or one-to-one correspondence between the elements in `listOne` and the elements in `listTwo`.

I can shuffle the elements in `listOne` as follows:

```
listOne = RandomSample[listOne, Length[listOne]];
```

However, is there a way for me to perform the above shuffling operation while preserving the bijection $f$?  In other words, can I shuffle the elements in `listOne` and `listTwo` in precisely the same manner?

Comment: p.s. There's no need for `Length[listone]`.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I just saw your comment.  I was a little slow on the pickup for rule replacement, but I think I get it now.

Comment: Personally I don't see this as a duplicate. Could one of those who closed the question show how one of the answers to the other question can be applied to this question?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch To my mind, both of the highest-voted answers there apply to this question quite directly, so much so that I don't know what else to add.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I disagree. Can you post an answer below showing one of those methods you mentioned giving the same result as e.g. Kubas answer. After which I will humbly apologize.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I agree with Mike Honeychurch; those seem to require that one list start off life ordered. [If I'm wrong, please accept Mike's humble apology..]

Comment: @DanielLichtblau thank you for offering my apology :) To me one problem relates to sorting and the other to mixing. Perhaps you should also vote to re-open?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Well, the only difference is that in that question, the shuffling is specific - it is sorting of one of the lists (and the others follow), while here it is arbitrary. But this does not change the methods used in any significant ways. For example, for the method based on `Transpose`, described in an accepted answer, one only needs to change `Sort` by `RandomSample[]`. The important thing, which is, forcing all other lists to undergo the same transformation, is not changed by this generalization.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Apology accepted :)

Comment: @Leonid Shifrin I'm not following you here. Example: suppose we do the following. `list1 = {1, 5, 6, 2, 7};
list2 = {a, b, c, d, e};
list1[[2 ;; 4]] = list1[[4 ;; 2 ;; -1]];` Also suppose we do not know specifically what was done to rearrange `list1`. How would responses to the other post do corresponding rearranging of `list2`?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I was taking for granted that the exact shuffling operation (ordering) is known. I thought this follows from the exact wording of the question. If this is not so, then I take my words back.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Can't make that assumption: In the OP example it is done with `RandomSample` so it's not repeatable unless a specific random seed is first set and then reset.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Well, there is `FindPermutation`...Besides, one can shuffle `Transpose[{listOne,listTwo]` instead of just `listOne`. I thought it was more important to stress the methods which either use ordering or shuffle things together, and those are described in those answers.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau And if you look at the accepted answer here, it also uses explicit ordering. I think that if the questions have very similar accepted answers, this is also an indication that they are likely duplicates.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just create an ordering list and use `Part`:

```
listOne = {1, 2, 3};
listTwo = {4, 5, 6};

order = RandomSample[Range[Length[listOne]]]
(* {2, 3, 1} *)

listOne[[order]]
(* {2, 3, 1} *)

listTwo[[order]]
(* {5, 6, 4} *)
```

Comment: +1 Geez I normally always choose `Part` over other methods but overlooked that. My morning coffee hasn't kicked in yet -- brain still frozen

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch, I have a time-zone advantage, my brain has been steeping in coffee all day :-)

Answer (score 6):

If it's a bijection you can for example do this:

```
s1 = RandomSample[listOne]
s2 = s1 /. MapThread[Rule, {listOne, listTwo}, 1]
```

Comment: I would have gone with `Dispatch@Thread[Rule[listOne, listTwo]]`. Not sure but might be faster for large lists.

Comment: @Kuba Thanks it's good to know that you can do this.

Comment: This doesn't work if `listOne` contains duplicates.  (Since the question is about *Mathematica* lists/arrays, other site users should be aware of this limitation.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 OP gives the assumption that it is bijection. So there are no duplicates, or if there are they are reffering to duplicate positions in the second list. Or I missed something?

Comment: A one-to-one correspondence between two `Lists`, which are ordered and permit duplicates, is different than a one-to-one correspondence between sets.  The site being about *Mathematica*, it seems fair to presume that an array is a `List`, not a mathematical set.  Because the Q&A format is for everyone, I think the distinction ought to be made clear for those who would adapt a solution to their own use-case.  If sets are meant - I agree the possibility is suggested by "bijection" - then the question should make that clear. I had a similar disagreement about another of the OP's questions. :)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I will focus on this in the weekend. But I can't agree by far. Yes, *Mathematica* is about lists but but bijection between lists is for me that what I've described. You, imo, are describing bijection between positions/indices. This interpretation seems to me unnatural in this context.

Comment: You've described Simon's answer beautifully. ;)  And yes, in an ordered set (e.g. an n-tuple), each value is paired with its position.  There are many cases where one needs to reorder a second array according to how another was shuffled, and a permutation is normally defined to be a bijection (e.g. reordering rows/columns of matrices).  Btw, no one has answered in terms of the function `f`, and I would say **nothing** needs to be done to preserve `f`: `f[x]` is unaffected by the position of `x` in a list.  For instance `f` might be defined by `MapThread[(f[#1] = #2)&, {listOne, listTwo}]`.

Answer (score 6):

Although I have used Simon's method many times I think it is somewhat cleaner in this case to transpose the data, shuffle, and transpose again:

```
l1 = {a, b, c, d, e};
l2 = {v, w, x, y, z};

RandomSample[{l1, l2}\[Transpose]]\[Transpose]
```

> ```
> {{e, c, b, a, d}, {z, x, w, v, y}}
> ```

The `\[Transpose]` symbol appears as <sup>T</sup> in the Front End:

[image]

Comment: I agree that this is cleaner. In fact I'd normally only use the method I posted if there was some need later on to undo the shuffle.